# Livepatch causing fatal overheating

Tags: 20.04, overheating, canonical-livepatch

For the past few months I have had issues on Ubuntu 20.04 where, on startup, my system begins overheating and temperatures shoot up over 90 C before all of my startup applications could open. I actually ended up purchasing a MacBook Pro because it was such a difficult problem to diagnose - to this day, I am not completely sure what was causing it. However, a few days ago, I started up my system again and noticed a log entry stating that `livepatch: 'lkp_Ubuntu_5_4_0_47_51_generic_73': unpatching complete`. I turned off Livepatch and since then, my system has not overheated once and I've been able to resume using it like normal.

Any explanation/assistance in debugging would be greatly appreciated, as I am not well-versed in these issues.